# pl-sql clob data issue

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi getting below error

```
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.
```

when i run the following pl-sql code

```
 DECLARE    
    type c_list is varray (6000) of varchar2(50);    
    name_list c_list := c_list();    
    counter integer :=0;    
    n number;    
    ADDHDR VARCHAR2(5000);    
    new_envelope clob:=NULL;    
BEGIN    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000);    
    FOR n in 1..1000 LOOP    
        counter := counter + 1;    
        name_list.extend;    
        name_list(counter)  := 'ABCNDFHDDJJ';    
        dbms_output.put_line('Customer('||counter ||'):'||name_list(counter));    
    END LOOP;

    for i in name_list.first .. name_list.last loop    
        ADDHDR := CONCAT(ADDHDR,'<ADDITIONAL_START>');    
        ADDHDR := CONCAT(ADDHDR, CONCAT('<START>', CONCAT('ADDR-KYC-ABCD-PRD-LDB-SMS-OR-START', '</START>')));    
        ADDHDR := CONCAT(ADDHDR, CONCAT('<ENDED>', CONCAT(name_list(i), '</ENDED>')));    
        ADDHDR := CONCAT(ADDHDR, '</ADDITIONAL_START>');    
        dbms_output.put_line('PROCESSING');    

        new_envelope := new_envelope || ADDHDR;   
        ADDHDR:=''    
    end loop;    
    dbms_output.put_line(new_envelope);    
END;    
/
```

please help me to concat string(value greater than 4000 characters) to a clob data

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you declare `c_list` as `varray (6000) of varchar2(50)` when you use only 1000 elements and index by number and not by varchar?

Comment: Other than an obvious syntax error (fifth line from the bottom is missing the ; terminator), the issue - as Wernfried pointed out already - is that you are trying to use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE on a string that is too long for that function. You can truncate `new_envelope` within the argument to `PUT_LINE` if you want to see the first 4000 bytes; or you can chop it into small-enough pieces and inspect it with `PUT_LINE` in another loop, if really needed.

Comment: Ok, so in order to have `VARCHAR2(5000)`, you need Oracle 12c (that's a first) and second, you need `ALTER SYSTEM SET max_string_size=extended;`. You could then define it even as VARCHAR2(32000), but why not use `clob` instead (clob size = 4 GB - 1*DB_BLOCK_SIZE ; VARCHAR2 = 4000 bytes OR 32000 bytes, depending? Then, when you use CONCAT, make sure you don't exceed even the clob limit, not to mention the VARCHAR2 limit. Also, dbms_output has a limitation of the output size. If you so desperately want it printed out, you must SUBSTR the new_envelope, by say 4000 and print it in sets of 4000.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is this line `dbms_output.put_line(new_envelope);`

You cannot output such large strings. I assume this is just for debugging, i.e. actually not needed.

If you really need `dbms_output.put_line` then do it line by line.

Comment: :-) Debugging is definitely needed, especially when one is outputting such a long string. Line by line, or several lines at a time, or output to file and inspect there - are some of the ways the OP can do that debugging.